# What is the current physical theory of what causes the 'Morning Glory' roll cloud over Northern Australia?

Tags: atmospheric-science

Wikipedia shows an example [Morning Glory roll cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morning_Glory_cloud),
$\hspace{100px}$[image],
and briefly describes the landform and meteorological causes, but states

> The Morning Glory cloud is not clearly understood because their rarity means they have little significance in terms of rainfall or climate

**Question:**  Is there any definitive physical theory as to how these meteorological phenomena form?

Comment: The first paragraph in the section following your cited line suggests at least one method by which these clouds can form.  But given that the paragraphs following that one suggest that there are other methods by which it can form, it does not seem that there is a definitive theory.

Comment: @KyleKanos well, it means that Wikipedia does not have a definitive theory reported, not necessarily that there is no new research.

Comment: This is true. It's also true that meteorology is **not** my field, I just read the wiki link and responded with my first thoughts.

Comment: Have to say that I'm unsure about whether to tag this [tag:everyday-life].  I mean, on the one hand, it's basically asking about something mostly observed by non-physicists in non-scientific settings, but it also feels strange to call it "_everyday_".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that these clouds are in fact reasonably well understood. [Roger Smith](https://www.meteo.physik.uni-muenchen.de/~roger/), who seems to be something of an expert on these clouds, has several papers discussing the physics of Morning Glory clouds, many of which are linked from his "list of publications" page and can be viewed for free.

[This paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20080419045120/http://www.meteo.physik.uni-muenchen.de/~roger/Publications/EarthSciRev_1988_Smith.pdf) seems to be particularly good. I am not a meteorologist, either, but from what I have read they appear to be solitary waves (a.k.a., solitons) which are travelling in a sort of atmospheric waveguide. I am sorry I can't give you a better answer than that; please do look at the linked references.

Comment: That paper is perfect, I agree that paper is particular good and explains the phenomena very well.  Am happy to award the bounty to your answer.

Comment: Your link to the paper is now broken.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the link. In case it breaks again, here is the article's DOI: 10.1016/0012-8252(88)90069-4